# Rails 4 , database not showing all records, after error validation

Tags: database, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I have very practical error , in my own project the thing I did is: You have a blog post , and comment section at the very bottom of the page. Now , it's showing all comments from proper database, you can of course add comment by typing in your name (or nickname) and comment into form.

Now , if you pass validation everything is great, page reloads with new comment and new form.
But , if you don't pass validation error occurs , which I just can't get rid of.

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #32):

</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<% @mains.each do |main| %>
<tr>
<td><%= main.title %></td>
<td><%= main.body %></td>

Rails.root: /home/mateusz/Pulpit/Aptana3_Workspace/My_webpage
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/views/mains/learn_webdeb.html.erb:32:in `_app_views_mains_learn_webdeb_html_erb__433863331888888116_31266720'
app/controllers/mains_controller.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in create'
app/controllers/mains_controller.rb:22:in `create'
```

Validation by itself works great, I tried it by deleting this section presented above. After new database injection doesn't pass validation, I want my application to print all database records, and below that error message, saying why this injection didn't work, with new ready to go form.

Here you have this troublesome file:

```
...
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name:</th>
            <th>Comment:</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <% @mains.each do |main| %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= main.title %></td>
                <td><%= main.body %></td>
            </tr>
        <% end %>
    </tbody>
</table>

<%= form_for(@main) do |main| %>

    <div>
        <%= main.label :title %>
        <%= main.text_field :title %>
    </div>
    <div>
        <%= main.label :body %>
        <%= main.text_area :body %>
    </div>
    <div>
        <%= main.submit %>
    </div>

    <% if @main.errors.any? %>
    <div>
        <!-- ><h2><%= pluralize(@main.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2> -->
        <% @main.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <p><%= msg %></p>
        <% end %>
    </div>
<% end %>

<% end %>
```

Related controller code:

```
class MainsController < ApplicationController
  def learn_webdeb
    @main = Main.new
    @mains = Main.all
  end

  def motivation
  end

  def about
  end

  def books_courses
  end

  def contact
  end

  def create
    @main = Main.new(main_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @main.save
        format.html { redirect_to @main }
      else
        format.html { render action: "learn_webdeb" }
      end
    end
  end

  def show
    redirect_to :action => "learn_webdeb" # albo redirec_to learn_webdeb_path
  end

  private

    def main_params
      params.require(:main).permit(:title, :body) # podsumowujac pozwala na zmiane tylko title i body w classie main czyli w modelu.
    end

end
```

How should I change my code for this to work?

Comment: Post the related controller code.

Comment: Do you have any records in mains table?

Comment: Yes, I already added some data to database, few comments.

Comment: What is the output of `Main.all`?

Comment: Some rubbish: Name:  Comment:
Felippe Jakcostogram  Antonio, fakalto!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
fsafdsafasdf  asdfasdfasdf
lklk  pppp
ll  poiopi
fg  fg,
Here you have github link if it will help you https://github.com/BobcatMK/My_webpage

Comment: What happens when you give like this `<% @mains.try.each do |main| %>`?

Comment: Error happens:

TypeError in Mains#learn_webdeb

Showing /home/mateusz/Pulpit/Aptana3_Workspace/My_webpage/app/views/mains/learn_webdeb.html.erb where line #32 raised:

nil is not a symbol

Extracted source (around line #32):
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<% @mains.try.each do |main| %>
<tr>
<td><%= main.title %></td>
<td><%= main.body %></td>

Comment: Try log @mains from controller: `logger.debug "mains: #{@mains}`

Comment: I am not sure where should I put this code zishe.

Comment: In `learn_webdeb` method last line.

Comment: BTW your repo works fine for me. Perhaps reloading server or drop and migrate again will help.

Comment: I put it here:   def learn_webdeb
    @main = Main.new
    @mains = Main.all
    logger.debug "mains: #{@mains}"
  end. Result is error: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass, just like in the very beginning.

Comment: Yes, but in log, before this error, you should see a line `mains: %nil or something%`

Comment: I can't find anything matching mains: %nil or anything inside my development.log.

Comment: ok, what url are you visit then? I think this method doesn't call.

Answer (score 0):

Ok , I fixed it. I changed this code inside my mains controller

```
  def create
    @main = Main.new(main_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @main.save
        format.html { redirect_to @main }
      else
        format.html { render action: "learn_webdeb" }
      end
    end
  end
```

To this code:

```
 def create
    @main = Main.new(main_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @main.save
        format.html { redirect_to @main }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to learn_webdeb_path }
      end
    end
  end
```

Now everything works perfectly, after injecting database with invalid information, I'm redirected to the same page, error messages saying that data typed in are invalid are lacking, but this problem I can fix in no time. Thanks for help!